# How To Change Connection String at runtime using CTP5

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, entity-framework

all
I am trying to change the connection string at runtime, i am using CTP5,
when i change the connection string and the folder is empty EF throws:
Database 'C:...\bin\Debug\db.mdf' already exists. Choose a different database name.
Cannot attach the file 'C:...\bin\Debug\DB\db.mdf' as database 'DB'.
when the folder has db.ldf (The Log File) and db.mdf EF throws the same exception

Please Help...

Comment: I assume that "EF" means Entity Framework? If so, it might be useful to add that as a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Entity Framework 4 you can create an [ObjectContext with a connection string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb739017.aspx) as constructor argument. So you're free to use any connection string any time. If course it would help if the database structure matched the context :).

Answer (score 1):

You can change the app config and reload changes.

```
        // Open App.Config of executable
        System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

        // Copy the value of new connection string
        config.AppSettings.Settings["ConnectionString"].Value = "New Connection String";

        // Save the configuration file.
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

        // Force a reload of a changed section.
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```